# jQueryMobile PageTransition Speed

Tags: performance, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jQueryMobile 1.3.0 with PhoneGap/Cordova 2.4.0 and trying to figure out how to speed up the page transitions.  I have reduced page transitions to approx 50ms when running on my laptop, however, when deployed to iPhone 4 the page transitions slow down dramatically.

Scenario Transition from Page A to Page B.
I notice appox 500ms between "Page B - pagebeforecreate" event and "Page A - pageHide" event.

Here is what I have tried:

1. I have stripped out most code.
2. Verified Page A - pageRemove event is not firing thus taking no time.
3. Decreased animation duration in css from 350ms to 30ms. (this helped, but not enough)

   ```
   .slide.out,.slide.in {
       -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-out;
       -webkit-animation-duration:30ms;
   }
   ```
4. Tried both 'a' tag and div with changePage

   ```
   <a href="#pageB">Go</a>

   <div onclick="$.mobile.changePage('#pageB');">Go2</div>
   ```

Anyone have any thoughts on what jQueryMobile is doing between the two events that would take time.  My next step will be to start logging from inside jquerymobile code to narrow down where time is being spent.

I appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Mobile adds a 300ms delay by default to tap events - it's listening for things like double-taps and swipes. If you are not using any of these types of events, consider incorporating FastClick http://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-remove-the-300ms-delay-when-clicking-on-a-link-in-jquery-mobile which has solved my speed issues in my PhoneGap/jQueryMobile app.

Answer (score 0):

the fastest way you can disable Transition

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
                $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "none";
            });
   </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I still would like a transition, I just want to speed it up.  The visual affect doesn't seem to be the issue (I think) There seems to be a lag from the time that I touch a button to the time the transition starts.